# Why is DefaultButton not working?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following code:

```
<form id="frmLogOn" runat="server" DefaultButton="testbutton">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="testpanel" DefaultButton="testbutton">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="testbutton" OnClick="dotest" UseSubmitBehavior="True"/>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

If I click the button, the page does a postback and calls dotest(), as expected.

If I press the enter key while focused on the textbox nothing happens.

I have investigated, and found that `WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, target)` is being called when I type a different key (for example a letter or a number) but it is NOT being called when I press the enter key.

(Note I found it is called twice, and this is probably because I set the same DefaultButton for both the form and the panel).

Why is it not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I determined this was caused by the following in my master page:

```
<body onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13)" >
```

Works fine without it.